# Conditional distinct count based on a measure in DAX

Tags: ssas, dax, ssas-tabular, bism

I am trying to do this with DAX and unable to get the correct distinct count...

```
AccountID   OrderDate   Product     SalesAmount DiscountAmount
1023        Nov-14      Product001  $0          $5.00
1045        Nov-14      Product001  $30.00  $10.00
1023        Nov-14      Product002  $1.00       $0  
1089        Nov-14      Product001  $0          $5.00
2045        Nov-14      Product001  $50.00  $25.00
1045        Nov-14      Product001  $(30.00)    $0
```

**Q1.** How do I count Distinct Customers where Total Sales Amount was $0 (Answer is 2, 1045, 1089) - see here I want to ignore 1023 because the total Sales amount for that account is not $0.

I tried to create a measure:

```
TotalCustomers:=CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Table1[AccountID]), 'Table1')
```

And then added this:

```
ZeroCustomers:=CALCULATE([TotalCustomers], FILTER('Table1', [Sum of SalesAmount]<>0))
```

But account 1023 gets counted and I get '3' for ZeroCutomers

**Q2.** How do I add up DiscountAmount for Customers where Total Sales Amount was $0 (Answer $15)

This is an extension to Q1 - once I have figure out Q1 - I can probably figure this one out.

My other choice is to create a new table already summarized by AccountID - but then I wont be able to use slicer since I still want to slice by lets say Product and other Dimensions.

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have figured it out:

**Q1**

```
ZeroCustomers:=COUNTROWS (
    FILTER (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            VALUES ( Table1[AccountID] ),
            "TotalSalesAmount", CALCULATE ( SUM ( [SalesAmount] ) )
        ),
        [TotalSalesAmount] = 0
    )
)
```

**Q2**

```
ZeroCustomerDiscount:=CALCULATE(SUM([DiscountAmount]),
    FILTER (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            VALUES ( Table1[AccountID] ),
            "TotalSalesAmount", CALCULATE ( SUM ( [SalesAmount] ) )
        ),
        [TotalSalesAmount] = 0
    )
)
```

Please comment/reply if you have a better way of accomplishing the same.
Hope this helps other!

Answer (score 1):

How about:

`ZeroCustomers:=CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Table1[AccountID]), ALL(Table1), [Sum of SalesAmount]<>0))`

`ZeroCustomersDiscount:=CALCULATE(SUM([DiscountAmount]), ALL(Table1), [Sum of SalesAmount]<>0))`

I think your previous attempt did not work due to how DAX handles filters and groupings.  I wish I could give you a more detailed explanation but I am still learning myself.